# PHP writing to file on server

Tags: php, lamp

I'm  trying to write to a file on my local server and I can't figure out why, I haven't found any good reason why what I'm doing should not work.

What I've tryed:

```
file_put_contents("./lol.txt", "Contents");
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/lil.txt", "Contents");
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "lal.txt", "Contents");
file_put_contents("lel.txt", "Contents");
```

I will provide any additional info if needed.

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: First of all you should dump "$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/lil.txt"" path and be sure that file doesn't exists. Next, I suggest check your php log file for more details. Do you have file system permissions to write file to that folder ?

Comment: file_put_contents() returns false and there was no output to console soo I searched a bit and used error_get_last()['message'] and it returned "...failed to open stream: Permission denied" which I found on other stack answers to similar problems (ex: just change somefile.txt permissions) but it didn't occur to me until now that I should've change the entire directory permissions (chmod +777 dirname), anyways that's what did it for me, thank you @AmitGaud, I didn't think to check more for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use realpath — Returns canonicalized absolute pathname

file_put_contents(realpath("somedirectory/somefile.txt"),$content);

> and check the permission for folder and file whether you have write
>   access.

Comment: as I've said in the comments above, indeed it was a permission problem, thank you!